# Showing that $U(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ is a coalgebra

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, hopf-algebras, coalgebras

We know that there is a coalgebra structure on $U(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ as follows for any $z\in \mathfrak{sl}_2$:
$$\Delta(z)=1\otimes z+z\otimes 1, \qquad \epsilon(z)=0.$$

Can someone be so kind to explain to me that why $\Delta$ is an algebra map?

Shouldn't we have $\Delta(zz´)=\Delta(z)\Delta(z´)$, for $z,z´\in \mathfrak{sl}_2$?

As we have $\Delta(z)\Delta(z´)=1\otimes zz´+z´\otimes z+z\otimes z´+zz´\otimes 1$ which as I understand is not equal to $\Delta(zz´)$!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is equal to $\Delta(z z')$ by definition. Remember that $z z'$ is not an element of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$. This definition of the comultiplication is hiding an extra step: it is defining the comultiplication on $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ only, and from here the comultiplication extends uniquely to $U(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ precisely because it must be an algebra homomorphism, so must satisfy $\Delta(z z') = \Delta(z) \Delta(z')$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But, sorry, I cannot understand what you are saying! Why it must be an algebra homomorphism? What is $\Delta(zz´)$? Why it has to be like that?

Comment: @user510716: the universal enveloping algebra of a Lie algebra is a Hopf algebra, and one of the Hopf algebra axioms is that the comultiplication is an algebra homomorphism. This means that you can specify the comultiplication *of a Hopf algebra* (not of an arbitrary coalgebra) by specifying its values on any set of generators of the algebra, and that is what this definition is doing. $\Delta(z z') = \Delta(z) \Delta(z')$ by definition, and it is the quantity you already calculated.

Comment: I should mention that it's not obvious that this definition is well-defined yet, in that it's not yet obvious that two different calculations of $\Delta$ for an arbitrary element of $U(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ will give the same answer. For that you need to show that $\Delta$ is compatible with the relations imposed to construct the universal enveloping algebra, which means showing that $\Delta([z, z']) = [\Delta(z), \Delta(z')]$ where the bracket on the LHS is the Lie bracket and the bracket on the RHS is the commutator bracket. This is straightforward.